# How do I get Ajax working in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) and I'm getting stuck at the point where I'm trying to get AJAX functionality to work.

I have a 'follow / unfollow' button on a user profile page that I want to dynamically update when it is clicked. The code I've tried implementing is as follows:

***_follow.html.erb:***

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.
                          build(:followed_id => @user.id), :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

***_unfollow.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
             :html => { :method => :delete }, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Unfollow" %></div>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, I've used the ':remote => true' call to tell the controller to go with the js implementation of the page (see following code):

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, the actual javascript never updates on the page - when I look in the logs it even says that it has rendered the new element... but it won't change the view of the page.

Any thoughts on what's happening here? Do I need to do something else in a configuration file to get javascript / Ajax to work for this application?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sorry I'm a little busy now, but here is something that could help you if you're not familiar with rjs http://railscasts.com/episodes/archive?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rjs

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bit that actually updates the page. I.E the rjs file.

API here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html

That will have code like

```
update_page do |page|
  page.insert_html :bottom, 'list', "<li>#{@item.name}</li>"
  page.visual_effect :highlight, 'list'
  page.hide 'status-indicator', 'cancel-link'
end
```

Also you don;t mention what version of rails you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for your note - I'm using Rails 3.0.3. In terms of the rjs file - I've got a js.erb file that I think should be updating the page, but it doesn't seem to be working. The code for that is:

create.js.erb:


$("follow_form").update("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>")
$("followers").update('<%= "#{@user.followers.count} followers" %>')

I'll check out the API link you note above. Hopefully something there will make things click.

Thanks again!

Comment: You using the default javascript libraries with rails 3? Or the jQuery api ?

Comment: In general your code looks right. I would suggesting using firebug to check the response, from the ajax call, have you tried that? You know how?

Answer (score 0):

I' using Rails 3.1.1 and had the same issue following the Rails 3.0 tutorial. In the version update Rails has moved away from Prototype and started using jQuery. To correct the old version of the javascript I had to update the create/destroy.js.erb.

You can read about it in [chapter 13](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#sec%3aprototype_to_jquery). It boils down to adding a "#" in front of your tag id, and replacing the ".update" call with ".html".